# How to use option value in wordpress using ajax and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing on plugin where in one stage i want make use of ajax using jquery for select box, below is my code , i done know how to use ajax in wordpress can anyone please help me

```html
<select id="payment_status">           
                        <option value="Payment Due">Payment Due</option>
                        <option value="Payment Completed">Payment Completed</option>
                        </select>
```

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#payment_status").change(function(){
                                jQuery.ajax({
                                type:"post",
                                    url:ajaxurl,
                                data:  {action: 'test.php',keyname:$('#payment_status option:selected').val()}
                                    // alert($('#payment_status option:selected').val());
                            })
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your js code must be look like on this

```
    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.love-button', function() {
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'post_love_add_love',
            post_id : post_id
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            alert(response)
        }
    });
});
```

and add this part of code into the functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );

function post_love_add_love() {
    $love = get_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'post_love', true );
    $love++;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) { 
        update_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'post_love', $love );
        echo $love;
    }
    die();
}
```

It's only example how using ajax in WordPress.

Comment: i am developing plugin so i want that data display in my admin area , already i displayed few data , i want to display there, so this function.php what you said , should i implement on my plugin main code